# Focus on checkbox without text Java SWT

Tags: java, swt, rcp

I'm using Eclipse RCP Application with SWT and I'm trying to set focus on checkbox without text.
The focus doesn't appeared if I use Tabulator Key. I already see if I set the text on my check box it's work, but this is not the requirment.
Exist any way to force eclipse to focus on checkbox without text?
Thank you !

Comment: Show us an [mcve]

Comment: Please provide some clear information with code snippet if possible. It might help us to provide a proper solution

Comment: Composite comp = WF.createComposite(parent, CEC.NONE);
comp.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,false));
Utils.makeLabel(comp, "Test");
Composite row1 = WF.createComposite(comp, CEC.NONE);
row1.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,false));
check1 = new Button(row1, SWT.CHECK);
Utils.makeLabel(row1, "Test");
check2 = new Button(row1, SWT.CHECK);
Utils.makeLabel(row1, "Test");
check3 = new Button(row2, SWT.CHECK);

Comment: @BogdanVorobet Please edit your question to include the code instead of putting it in a comment